# Create JSON data NVD3 Chart using Java

Tags: java, json, nvd3.js

I working on NVD3 chart where need to create JSON data for chart as below:

```
[{ 
  "key" : "North America" , 
  "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832] ]
},

{ 
  "key" : "Africa" , 
  "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832] ]
},

{ 
  "key" : "South America" , 
  "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832] ]
}]
```

Would somebody please help me create above JSON data using Java as I am trying to create this structure since last 3 hours not successful yet.

Here is the Plunker link: [Stacked Area Chart NVD3](http://plnkr.co/edit/CIGW0o?p=preview)

Here is the live JSON data example which I want to create in JAVA: [JSON example data](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedAreaData.json)

Comment: I am not sure if NVD3 works with Java! or did you mean JavaScript ?

Comment: Thanks. I am making AJAX call on server and sending JSON response back to client side HTML and render the data to create charts. It works with my string data which I created on server (Java) sending back to client. Only problem is making above structure JSON data.

Comment: I see you didn't understand my questions and voted negative without any reason. Have you ever worked in Java? Not sure what do you mean by NVD3 don't work in Java where I have to replace JSON data which is AJAX call to the server. Would you please tell me reason to give negative vote?

Comment: If you had mentioned `I am making AJAX call on server and sending JSON response back to client side HTML and render the data to create charts.` I think it would have made the question much more clear.

Comment: As I had mentioned in the heading clearly which says I wanted to create only JSON data for NVD3 charts using Java. I am wondering why you didn't ask me before giving me negative vote. If you are generous think twice giving anybody negative vote otherwise clarify before voting or never show your negative genius approach this is my advice to you. Anyway below is solution:

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution found by myself:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class CreateNVD3JSONDataJava {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("values", new JSONArray(new Long[][]{{1025409600000L,23L},{1028088000000L,19L},{1030766400000L,21L},{1033358400000L,22L}}));     
    jo.put("key", "North America");     

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    ja.put(jo);
    ja.put(jo); 
    ja.put(jo); 

    System.out.println(ja);
  }
}
```

Comment: Except that you'd need three `jo` objects in "real life", since the values would be different.  Don't make the mistake of using a single object and changing it between `put` operations, as you will change the values you're already "put".

Comment: I completely agree. Thanks! I have edited code as below:

Comment: (It's amazing how often the mistake of reusing a single object/array occurs when constructing JSON.)

Comment: I believe this is not real time data process we discussing but just get an idea to create data.

Answer (score 0):

Edited code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class CreateNVD3JSONDataJava {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("values", new JSONArray(new Long[][]{{1025409600000L,23L},{1028088000000L,19L},{1030766400000L,21L},{1033358400000L,22L}}));     
    jo.put("key", "North America"); 
    ja.put(jo);

    jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("values", new JSONArray(new Long[][]{{1025409600000L,23L},{1028088000000L,19L},{1030766400000L,21L},{1033358400000L,22L}}));     
    jo.put("key", "Africa");
    ja.put(jo);

    jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("values", new JSONArray(new Long[][]{{1025409600000L,23L},{1028088000000L,19L},{1030766400000L,21L},{1033358400000L,22L}}));     
    jo.put("key", "South America");
    ja.put(jo);         

    System.out.println(ja);

  }
}
```

Output:

```
[
{
    "values": [
        [
            1025409600000,
            23
        ],
        [
            1028088000000,
            19
        ],
        [
            1030766400000,
            21
        ],
        [
            1033358400000,
            22
        ]
    ],
    "key": "North America"
},
{
    "values": [
        [
            1025409600000,
            23
        ],
        [
            1028088000000,
            19
        ],
        [
            1030766400000,
            21
        ],
        [
            1033358400000,
            22
        ]
    ],
    "key": "Africa"
},
{
    "values": [
        [
            1025409600000,
            23
        ],
        [
            1028088000000,
            19
        ],
        [
            1030766400000,
            21
        ],
        [
            1033358400000,
            22
        ]
    ],
    "key": "South America"
  }
]
```